# Deploy a Python script with Saltstack & test if it works correctly

Tags: python, linux, centos7, salt-stack

Hi guys im trying to deploy a python script to a agent node, but im trying to figure out how you can test the script if it works correctly from the salt-master.

Setup:

- master
- agent minion

with saltstack i should install al the needed packages on the Agent to run a python script correclty right?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry you are asking for a complete solution. Not the answer to a question

Comment: Would be kind if you could post that as answer too :) thanks in advance

Comment: Why test it on the server, when you can write unit tests and test it whenever you make changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Python installation on minion's side as Python is installed with salt-minion and required for modules execution, but can be not in binary-search PATH.

1. Format your script as Saltstack modules and locate inside _modules folder - https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/
2. Run `salt '<minion_id>' saltutil.sync_modules`
3. Check if module is available from minion: `salt '<minion_id>' sys.list_modules`
4. Run it in format  `salt '<minion_id>' <module_name>.<function>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the Python package on the agent if it does not yet exist there in order to run the python script, correct.

Installing that package will need to be part of your Salt state for the agent. You can test if the script works correctly on the master once it is there. like this:

```
root@salt-master$ salt 'agent-hostname' cmd.run 'python /path/to/script/name-of-script.py'
```